# want to get value of productCode while clicking on edit button

Tags: angular6

i want to get value of productCode while clicking on edit button

```
 <tr *ngFor=" let x of response">
            <td ><img src = "{{x.productPrimaryImage}}"></td>
              <td>{{x.productCode}}</td>
            <td>{{x.productName}}</td>
            <td>{{x.status}}</td>
            <td>{{x.productCategories}}</td>

            <td>{{x.productMRP}}</td>
            <td>{{x.productSSP}}</td>
            <td>{{x.productYMP}}</td>
    <td><button class=" btn btn-info btn-sm" (click)"editProduct()">edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `editProduct` method takes a `productCode` parameter, you can pass it in like so:

```
<button class=" btn btn-info btn-sm" (click)"editProduct(x.productCode)">edit</button>
```